# Unable to use synonym of functions, procedures or seq in Oracle

Tags: oracle, synonym

I have created synonyms for functions/proc/seq in userid YYY from user id XXX.

```
create SYNONYM my_seq FOR XXX.my_seq
```

When I try to use the seq in user YYY, I am getting following error :

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

and with functions : **ORA-00904: : invalid identifier**

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: It is being shown in Synonyms column present in Sqldeveloper.

Comment: You need to fix GRANTS on the objects.

Comment: could you please help me with that? I am stubborn on Oracle DB actually :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to demonstrate with a simple example. I have two schemas on one server. Schema1 and Schema2.

I logon to Schema1 and run the script below.

```
-- Create sequence 
create sequence originalSeq
minvalue 1
maxvalue 999999999999999999999999
start with 1
increment by 10
cache 20;


GRANT SELECT ON originalSeq TO SCHEMA2;
```

Then I logon to Schema2 and run the following script.

```
    create or replace synonym pointertooriginalsreq
      for SCHEMA1.originalSeq;  

select pointertooriginalsreq.nextval from dual
```

this should work in all versions of **Oracle 8.1.7** upwards. Please let me know if you're still facing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide grants from XXX user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON my_seq TO YYY;
```